# Is it normal not know minimum pay until the end of the interview?

Tags: work-environment, human-resources

More and more often I am being contacted on various professional social networks by HR people with mail like this:

> Hi (your name), I'm interested in your profile so I would like to know if
>   you are intersted for an interview. We are (info about the company).

Since I'm currently happy with my job and since, in cases like this, I always think about trawling, I usually start to ask something like:

- what pay should I expect (where I intend the minimum pay)?
- what benefits should I expect?
- what type of employment contract should I expect?

But usually they answer: This will be explained after the interview. 
Is this normal or is this smell for a penny-pinching company?

Comment: If the first thing you say is "what's in it for me?", then you're suggesting that you only care about yourself, which is the opposite attitude of what companies are looking for.

Comment: "where I intend the minimum pay" what do you mean by this are you talking about base vs bonus here ?

Comment: No, I mean: as solutin developer your expected salary will be in this range...

Comment: Radu Murza: companies trying to recruit people who already have a job should understand that these will always be the questions they need to answer before being considered. If they're not willing to do that, they should only go after unemployed people (preferably chronically so).

Comment: If you read a little bit about negotiating, you'll realize that it's actually to your benefit not to discuss salary until the offer stage. The reason is, at the offer stage, the hiring manager has already decided that you are (currently) the best candidate for the position. That gives you leverage, especially if you think you've demonstrated that you can do more for the company (i.e. make them more money) than the bare minimum expected from the job description. Asking for a salary or range beforehand, or providing your own, can result in you "pricing yourself out" of a potentially good match.

Comment: @Aaronaught, but this is the case of the OP already having a good job.  Why would he waste time on interviewing/etc for a position that is potentially offering less compensation (benefits/money/etc)?

Comment: @Zoredache: Lots of people change jobs when they have what they consider to be a good job. They find *better* jobs. Everybody with ambition is trying to move up in their career. "Better" does not necessarily have to refer to financial compensation; above a certain range, the working conditions can often make a larger difference. The new position might be in a better location, entail more responsibilities or opportunities for promotion, offer flex time or telecommuting, have a more casual work environment, look good on a resume, have better job security... you don't know until you ask.

Comment: @Aaronaught `you don't know until you ask.`, but isn't that exactly what you are advocating against in your previous comment?  Or are you suggesting that interview with every random person that cold calls you, just in case one of them might be offering something better?

Comment: @Zoredache: Of course not, I'm saying that finding out about the company and the position is more useful than asking immediately about compensation (and they're more willing to give that information anyway).

Comment: @Aaronaught: An important phrase in my message has been pretty ignored: `I always think about trawling`. I don't feel like the current best candidate, I feel more like the one of the first matches on a professional social network. This is pretty frustrating.

Comment: @Mariano: Certainly if the message is impersonal or your skills don't seem to be a match, or maybe the position looks far too junior or refers to non-current information on your resume, then I would give it a pass, just like you. But that has nothing to do with salary or compensation information, and rarely has anything to do with the company itself - it's just typical recruiter behaviour. You'd be amazed at how lazy some of them are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have to disagree with the other answers here.  You should *always* know the rough salary before you interview.

Can you imagine preparing for an interview, booking time off, doing it, only to be told that the pay is several thousand less than what you're currently on?

Now - you won't get an *exact* salary out of most companies.  That will depend on what they think you're worth.

Most reputable companies will (depending on sector) say:

- Base salary £9,000 - OTE £35,000 (on target earnings / bonus etc)
- From £22,000 (This is the minimum they'll pay - maybe you'll get more.)
- Up to £33,000 (This is the top they can afford. You'll probably get less.)
- Between £19k - 24k Depending on experience (This is their range, you're unlikely to go outside it)
- In line with experience.  AVOID!  Their idea of experience is unlikely to be the same as yours...

In any case, before interviewing let them know your salary expectations.  If they won't give you their expected salary range (or any other details) I'd be *very* wary.

Now - all this is slightly dependent on your experience and the industry you're in.  It's never a good idea to go to an interview without an idea of what the remuneration is - be it salary, stock, free meals, etc.

Comment: Exactly. The problem here is: 1) you came to me, not contra 2) I'm happy with my current job, so is up to you make me "curious" about you (unless you are not stackexchange :) , google or apple). 3) I will not take a freeday to schedule an interview that I'll probably refuse (since the point n° 2)

Comment: Yes. Why should I waste my time preparing for a job interview if you won't give me any incentive.

Comment: +1 If they *really* want you to come for an interview, let them know the only way they can have a hope of luring you in is with an expected salary *range*, at he very least.

Comment: Good answer. I would add that if you don't want to give the "only in it for the money" impression, then before agreeing to an interview, I would respond with several questions *including* one about expected salary range. Ask some other questions about nature of the work, team size, etc.

Answer (score 5):

> But usually they answer: This will be explained after the interview.
>   Is this normal or is this smell for a penny-pinching company?

This is completely normal, and not necessarily the sign of a penny-pinching company.

Companies often don't want to discuss salary and benefits with someone until they are sure there is at least some level of mutual interest. In particular, they are often reluctant to hand out this information over social networks. Salary and benefit information and negotiation often take place in the last stages of interviewing.

If you are interested in the company, you can often get a sense of their benefits by looking at their company website. Many companies have a page or two about "why you should work here" that mentions benefits as well.

If you really need to know more specifics, and don't worry about coming across as someone who cares more about the money than about the specifics of the work, you can always say "I'm not interested unless this job pays at least $x". Then, you can decide your next step based on their response.

Comment: True, but as the OP stated, if an employee has a job already, why waste everyone's time? At least an acceptable range should be discussed prior to any interview commitments, since acceptable pay is a necessary but not sufficient condition of employment.  Companies refusing to do this are just wasting money...

Answer (score 3):

This is normal since payments vary between people.

They want you to impress them before they start to offer you anything.

Just because you say you know something doesn't mean that you actually know it, they need to get an insight of your knowledge and perhaps there are some issues with you; maybe you're very bad in socializing with your co-workers and so on.

Some companies give you a reasonable range but the interview and your experience and set of skills will determine where you end within he range, but usually it's not provided.

And in my experience you'll be the one asked how much you want and if they're pleased with you then they either give you a direct job offer or a counter offer so you must make sure that you know how much you deserve for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Generally employers like to keep as much control as possible over their hiring processes, which includes the discussion on pay and benefits. It's also fashionable for employees to pretend that they're not working in order to get paid but rather because they love their job. For both of these reasons it's become the norm that questions regarding pay and benefits don't come up until late in the interview stage. Asking these questions before an interview can come across as strange to many interviewers which is not something you want when actively searching for a job.

When you're in this situation you should have a general idea of your value as an employee as well as the average pay range for the positions you're looking for in your area. If you're then asking these kinds of questions too early in the interviewing process you signal that you either don't know the value of your skills or don't trust the interviewer to make a market-appropriate offer.

However, this changes when you're the one being contacted for a position. It's entirely reasonable to request details on the position as well as the pay range when you're being cold called by a company or recruiter. This saves both parties valuable time when either has certain requirements that they can't budge on. Reasonable recruiters shouldn't balk at discussing the pay range for a position they're trying to fill prior to an interview. I should note that I've gotten the impression that in some regions and cultures recruiters are more likely to be unreasonably attached to controlling the interview process.

No matter who initiated the conversation, the tone in which you ask these questions is important as even reasonable questions can rub recruiters the wrong way if you come across as overly blunt or self-concerned.

Now, if recruiters won't even answer a question as simple as what kind of contract you should expect, that's a pretty big red flag for either the recruiter or the position. It could be that the recruiter doesn't have any actual positions available but is looking to build up a collection of profiles.